# Making wide table fit bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th class="col-md-1">Id</th>
                 <th class="col-md-1">Enabled</th>
                 <th class="col-md-1">Shortcode</th>
                 <th class="col-md-1">Keyword</th>
                 <th class="col-md-1">Session Based</th>
                 <th class="col-md-1">Application SMS Endpoint</th>
                 <th class="col-md-2">Application MMS Endpoint</th>
                 <th class="col-md-2">Date From</th>
                 <th class="col-md-2">Date To</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1502</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>*</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://google.com/sms</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>10 March 2014 19:04:15</td>
                <td>01 January 2100 00:00:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1212</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>*</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://somewhere.local:8080/</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>06 March 2014 14:00:12</td>
                <td>04 March 2034 15:20:05</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1023</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>*</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://www.google.com/sms</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>26 February 2014 16:35:52</td>
                <td>01 January 2100 00:00:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1464</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>00LONG</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>10 March 2014 07:19:19</td>
                <td>10 March 2034 07:19:19</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1450</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>10 March 2014 04:25:29</td>
                <td>10 March 2034 04:25:29</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1384</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>07 March 2014 04:25:40</td>
                <td>07 March 2034 04:25:40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1397</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>AB</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>07 March 2014 08:39:20</td>
                <td>07 March 2034 08:39:20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1393</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>ABRANTEE</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>07 March 2014 06:59:16</td>
                <td>07 March 2034 06:59:16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1446</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>BREAKFAST</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>08 March 2014 12:03:46</td>
                <td>08 March 2034 12:03:46</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1514</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>CAMPAIGN</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>11 March 2014 04:31:50</td>
                <td>11 March 2034 04:31:50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1515</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>CAMPAIGN1</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>11 March 2014 04:47:27</td>
                <td>11 March 2034 04:47:27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1472</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>10 March 2014 08:26:27</td>
                <td>10 March 2034 08:26:27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1410</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>GJGJTY</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>07 March 2014 10:00:34</td>
                <td>07 March 2034 10:00:34</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1390</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>JYJYTJY</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>07 March 2014 05:19:42</td>
                <td>07 March 2034 05:19:42</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1322</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>LONGCODE</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>06 March 2014 09:28:39</td>
                <td>06 March 2034 09:28:39</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1471</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>LONGCODETHIRTYCAHRACTERKEYWORD</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>10 March 2014 08:26:27</td>
                <td>10 March 2034 08:26:27</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1319</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>MARV</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>06 March 2014 08:46:53</td>
                <td>06 March 2034 08:46:53</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1503</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>MUM</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://www.ff.com/sms</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>10 March 2014 19:16:52</td>
                <td>17 March 2014 19:16:52</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1447</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>R</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>08 March 2014 12:03:46</td>
                <td>08 March 2034 12:03:46</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1281</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>+44123456789</td>
                <td>S2</td>
                <td>False</td>
                <td>http://ggole.com</td>
                <td>NOTUSED</td>
                <td>06 March 2014 05:31:51</td>
                <td>06 March 2034 05:31:51</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When no CSS is applied it auto widths to be 1400px or so. I have found for Twitter Bootstrap  I need to apply `width: auto !important` for it to not be 100% width by default however my table still goes outside the parent container. I have tried to apply column widths using `col-md-1` attributes but doesn't seem to make much difference

I have found if you apply `table-layout:fixed` to a table it will conform to a defined width.

My table is in a `<div class="table-responsive">` so should I set a style for my table as `width:90%` to try and make it fit within the parent container?

I'm just wondering if there is a known solution to solve the problem of having a very wide table with Bootstrap fitting the parent container width?

Thanks

Answer (score 60):

Adding style to the `<td>` seemed to fix this

`<td style ="word-break:break-all;">`

Comment: Thank you for this. I just had same problem and this solved it.

Comment: Another thing you can add to is "font-size: 90%;" so text will be smaller all together and there is less breaking of lines in columns. You can also bold text after making it smaller or set come color for easier read.

Comment: This worked for me. But a better alternative might be "word-break: break-word" which will try to break on word boundaries instead of in the middle of a word

Comment: I used `<td style ="word-break:break-word;">` and this achieved the behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 25):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve?

A table inside a panel-body that doesn't overflow due to the panel-body padding?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>A</th>
                            <th>B</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4215/

and your full sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4216/

Comment: This works perfectly. Adding `table-condensed` class to `<table>` lessens table's paddings.

Comment: the second fiddle is the one that actually solves the issue, surrounding the table with `.table-responsive` div.

Comment: Adding `table-sm` class to `<table>` lessens table's paddings in [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/). It should be like `<table class="table table-sm">`

Answer (score 15):

You must add this class to the container so it will be like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive fixed-table-body">
```

OR

```
<div class="table-responsive table-body">
```

Comment: Confirmed to solve all my wordly problems, thank you dude

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the same issue by changing `<div class="container">...</div>` to `<div class="container-fluid">...</div>`

Answer (score 3):

Try applying `class="row"` for the `<tr>` elements.

> Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
>   Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

--  [Bootstrap css docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

note that Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding, so you might want to apply `class=container-fluid` for the table or a parent of it.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. If one of the columns has a decent sized URL it still overflows

Comment: Well the question was how make the table fit bootstrap container. it's done right?

Comment: @Jon you haven't done what i mentioned in the answer.. adding `row` for all<tr>. You also have to add `class="col-md-1"` for each <tr> like you've done for the `<th>` in question, their total should not exceed 12 per each <tr>. Let me know what happens..

Comment: Sorry. That demo didnt show your answer but doing as you suggested didnt seem to work

Comment: Adding <td style ="word-break:break-all;> seemed to fix it